# Platform independent composer post-install-cmd script

Tags: composer-php

Lets say my project has following structure

```
project\
    templates\
    web\assets\
composer.json
```

When running the `composer update` by default symlink to my project is created in `vendor/` directory. I would like to create a custom post-install-cmd script that would create symlink to `templates\` and `web\assets\` folder in a different location.

Since my team is working on Windows/Mac/Linux I planned in running a simple php commands to make this happen. I can't seem to figure out where to start ...

The thing is, I can't figure out where is my current location when starting a php script? I've tried creating an empty file to see where it creates it, but it doesn't even create it.

This is what I wish to get working

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php -r \"symlink('/vendor/project/templates', '/templates/project');\"",
        "php -r \"symlink('/vendor/project/web/assets', '/web/project/assets');\""
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove leading slashes from paths - at least on unix it will be interpreted as absolute path and definitely will not point to your project.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php -r \"symlink('vendor/project/templates', 'templates/project');\"",
        "php -r \"symlink('vendor/project/web/assets', 'web/project/assets');\""
    ]
}
```

If you want a bulletproof solution, you should probably create PHP helper class and use `__DIR__` lub composer API to define correct paths. See [examples in documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts).

Comment: True, didn't help tho :/ I'm currently on Windows. It looks like symlink doesn't do anything, I will give it a try with a .php file and see if it makes a difference.